# Подсчет подключенных клиентов к tcp серверу

Tags: golang, инспекция-кода

Есть tcp сервер

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "net"
        "log"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Listening on port 8080")
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp","localhost:8080")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer lis.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := lis.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
    }
        go handleConnect(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnect(conn net.Conn) {

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    dataSize, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    message := buffer[:dataSize]
    fmt.Println("received message: ", string(message)) 
    _, err = conn.Write(message)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("message sent: ", string(message))
    conn.Close()
}
```

Надо посчитать подключенных клиентов и если их число равно трем то приостановить подключения до тех пор пока один из клиентов не отсоединится.

Вопрос: как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Всё уже придумано: [LimitListener](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/netutil#LimitListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать свой [net.Listener](https://godoc.org/net#Listener)
[Тут](https://kylelemons.net/browse/gitweb.cgi/go/daemon.git/blob/HEAD:/listen.go) пример. Смотрите waitConn и WaitListener, они тречат подключения, правда не лимитируют.

В вашем же случае можно сделать так:

```
type LimitedListener struct {
    sync.Mutex
    net.Listener
    sem chan bool
}

func NewLimitedListener(count int, l net.Listener) *net.LimitedListener {
    sem := make(chan bool, count)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        sem <- true
    }
    return &net.LimitedListener{
        Listener: l,
        sem:      sem,
    }
}

func (l *LimitedListener) Addr() net.Addr { /* ... */ }
func (l *LimitedListener) Close() error { /* ... */ }
func (l *LimitedListener) Accept() (net.Conn, err) {
    <-l.sem 
    return c, nil
}

type LimitedConn struct { /* ... */ }

func (c *LimitedConn) Close() error {
    c.sem <- true
}
```

Надеюсь пример поможет понять вам идею.